# Solving 9 simultaneous linear equations using two 3x3 matrices symbolically

Tags: equation-solving

*I am very new to Mathematica, so sorry for my ignorance*

I have 9 simultaneous equations on the form:
M=Zeros

Where M is a 3x3 matrix with linear expressions of 9 variables as entries. And Zeros is a 3x3 matrix with only zeros as entries. Is there a way to easily solve this?

I was thinking something like:
`Solve[M == Zeros, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}]`
where a-i is the unknowns.

2x2 example of the problem:

```
( {{a + b, b + c},{c + d, d + a}}) == ({{0, 0},{0, 0}})
```

Or maybe there is an easy way to convert this into 9 equations?

Comment: `Thread[Flatten[{{a+b,b+c},{c+d, d+a}}]==Flatten[{{0,0},{0,0}}]]` gives you `{a+b==0,b+c==0,c+d==0,a+d==0}` OR `Reduce[{{a+b,b+c},{c+d,d+a}} == {{0,0},{0,0}}, {a,b,c,d}]` gives you `b == -a && c == a && d == -a`

Comment: Why not solve directly? `Solve[{{a + b, b + c}, {c + d, d + a}} == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {a, b, c, d}]`

Comment: @bills - Or just `Solve[{{a + b, b + c}, {c + d, d + a}} == 0, {a, b, c, d}]` or even `Solve[{{a + b, b + c}, {c + d, d + a}} == 0]`